# Python Numpy, пересечение двумерных массивов

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется два массива np:

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 5],
    [5, 6, 3, 3],
    [6, 8, 1, 7],
    [9, 5, 1, 9],
    [6, 4, 8, 12],
    [5, 9, 2, 14],
])

b = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 6],
    [6, 8, 1, 8],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [5, 9, 2, 9],
])
```

Необходимо создать два массива a_ и b_. В эти массивы должны быть записаны строки, которые повторяются в обоих массивах по первым 3м элементам. То есть должны получиться такие массивы:

```
a_ = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 5],
    [6, 8, 1, 7],
    [5, 9, 2, 14],
])

b_ = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 3],
    [6, 8, 1, 8],
    [5, 9, 2, 9],
])
```

Ничего умнее цикла придумать не могу, может есть какая то функция о которой я не знаю и не могу нагуглить.

Можно в принципе поудалять неподходящие строки на месте прям в массивах a и b не создавая новых массивов a_ и b_ если есть возможность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извиняюсь, сейчас не могу комментарий написать

```
a1 = a[:, :-1]
b1 = b[:, :-1]
m = (a1[:, None] == b1).all(-1).any(1)
print(a[m])

[[ 1  2  3  5]
 [ 6  8  1  7]
 [ 5  9  2 14]]
```

Comment: Здорово, коротко, но пока не совсем ясно как работает.

Comment: По мне, так очень красиво.

Answer (score 3):

`select` фильтрует массив `a` относительно `b`. Сложность по памяти и времени линейная:

```
def select(a, b):
    def key(v):
        return tuple(v[:3])

    b_set = set(map(key, b))
    return a[np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: key(v) in b_set, 1, a)]
```

Например два массива по 100 тысяч строк укладываются в полторы секунды:

```
h = 1000
n = 100000
a = np.random.randint(0, high=h, size=(n, 4))
b = np.random.randint(0, high=h, size=(n, 4))

print(select(a, b))
print(select(b, a))
```

> ```
> $ time python test.py
> [[290 811 482 291]
>  [227 427 977 574]
>  [904 141 433 193]
>  [309 933 872 123]
>  [341 585 128 447]
>  [ 15 989 351  81]
>  [303  64 711 972]
>  [653 212 892 430]]
> [[303  64 711 838]
>  [309 933 872 560]
>  [653 212 892 127]
>  [ 15 989 351 955]
>  [904 141 433 975]
>  [227 427 977 508]
>  [341 585 128 518]
>  [290 811 482 830]]
>
> real  0m1.134s
> user  0m1.324s
> sys   0m0.360s
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой SciPy и функцией cdist для определения парных расстояний между векторами. Если расстояния равны нулю, то вектора равны. Для скорости, наверное, лучше использовать расстояние Хэмминга (matching).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 5],
    [5, 6, 3, 3],
    [6, 8, 1, 7],
    [9, 5, 1, 9],
    [6, 4, 8, 12],
    [5, 9, 2, 14],
])

b = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 6],
    [6, 8, 1, 8],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [5, 9, 2, 9],
])

ind1, ind2=np.nonzero(cdist(a[:, :-1],b[:, :-1], 'matching')==0)
print(a[ind1,:])
print(b[ind2,:])
```

Как правильно заметил  Stanislav Volodarskiy, скорость и потребление памяти на больших массивах будут не очень хорошими, поэтому вот еще более быстрый вариант:

```
import numpy as np

h=1000
n=100000
a = np.random.randint(0, high=h, size=(n, 4))
b = np.random.randint(0, high=h, size=(n, 4))
def select(a, b):
    a1=np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: hash(x.tobytes()), 1, a[:,:3])
    b1=np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: hash(x.tobytes()), 1, b[:,:3])
    _,idx1, idx2=np.intersect1d(a1, b1, return_indices=True)
    print(a[idx1])
    print(b[idx2])
select(a,b)
```

Comment: 100000x4 не помещаются в память. Видимо, нужна квадратичная память.

Comment: Согласен, считается квадратично.